# 405 method not allowed error in AWS Cognito oauth2/token endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito UI for login using authorization code grant flow and successfully getting the authorization code. But getting an *405 method not allowed* error when post request is made to oauth2/token endpoint via postman

The app client is setup in Cognito User Pool with app secret passing appclientid:appclientsecret as authorization in base64 encoding.

Answer (score 25):

As stated in the documentation:

> Content-Type
>   Must always be 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Source:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Comment: Sometimes need someone to state something in bold text that "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" is not the same as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"... Thank you. Stitched myself up on this one.

Answer (score 9):

Use BasicAuth of Authentication and provide `Username`=`client_id`, `Password`=`client_secret`

Use `POST` method

Use `Body` = `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Dont forget to use `State` value in Body as well.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  In  my case I had to change the Accept header to `*/*`.

When I had it as `Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml` it responded with 405 to the /token endpoint.  Hopefully that helps somebody.

Answer (score 4):

I was writing code in c# for token with authorization_code grant type and all calls were failing with *405 Method Not Allowed* status.

According to AWS documentation following URL and parameters should be used

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token&
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'&
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj

grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=djc98u3jiedmi283eu928&
code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&
redirect_uri=com.myclientapp://myclient/redirect
```

After spending 2 hours, I found out, removing **&** from URL would solve the issue, so make sure your request looks like this

```
POST https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Authorization=Basic aSdxd892iujendek328uedj

grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=djc98u3jiedmi283eu928&
code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&
redirect_uri=com.myclientapp://myclient/redirect
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this error 405 method not allowed error in AWS Cognito `oauth2/token` endpoint by making my code as below mentioned, and it worked fine.
I took help from this link and use the correct format to mention both header and body parameters in the fetch request:

https://formcarry.com/documentation/fetch-api-example

```js
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": `Basic ${authData}`,
      "Accept": "application/json"            
    },
    body: `grant_type=${config.grant_type}&code=${code}&client_id=${config.clientId}&redirect_uri=${config.loginRedirectUri}`
  }
        
  fetch(`${config.domainUrl}/oauth2/token`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("access_token",data.access_token)
      fetchUserDetails(data.access_token)
    })
```

I used a config file to save variables.

```js
const config = {
  domainUrl: "https://domainname.auth.origin.amazoncognito.com",
  clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  loginRedirectUri: "http://localhost:8000/redirecturi",
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  logoutUri: "http://localhost:8000",
  clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just in case it helps anybody.

> I was facing a 405 in Postman while trying to retrieve the respective
> jwt tokens (id_token, access_token, refresh_token) using the
> grant_type as authorization_code.

reason being the headers section where I was using `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` as value for `Content-Type` i.e. with single quotes. So, when I removed these single quotes and only used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` right away, it started working.

Comment: This was exactly what fixed an issue I was having with Cognito where I was receiving the same 405 error.  Thanks @Prateek!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, although using client_credentials rather than authorization_code.

In Postman I was using basic auth with a valid `client_id`/`client_secret` as username/password, made sure the Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header was there, and set the body (`raw/json`) to:

```
{
"client_id": {client_id},
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"scope": {client_scope}
}
```

However, I was still getting the `405: Method Not Allowed` error.
I eventually figured out that I could switch the body type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman, re-entered the body parameters and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var strClientSecret = $"{"your_clientId"}:{"your_clientsecret"}";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        body.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        body.Add("client_id", "your_appclientid");
        body.Add("redirect_uri", "your_callbackurl");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
        var autho = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strClientSecret);
        var base64Autho = System.Convert.ToBase64String(autho);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Autho);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://your_domain.auth.ap-south-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token", content);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case after upgrade [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) from `v0.x.x` to `v1.x.x` I changed

`headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },`

to

`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },`

With capital letters in `Content-Type`

Answer (score 0):

And to make the picture complete, if your Host header is not set or not the same as the domain that you are posting to, you will also get a 405 (Method not allowed).